# genymotion BSOD windows 10

Tags: android, windows, genymotion, memory-corruption, bsod

I am new to android development, following a tutorial i downloaded android studios and genymotion. whenever i press start on genymotion  my computer instantly crashes. 
I have posted below the minidump from the crash.

any help is greatly appreciated

specs
windows 10
genymotion 5.1.22

```
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000096, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: ffffc58204c408b3, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffc581ffd36c70, Address of the context record for the exception that 
caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : 
e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000096 - {EXCEPTION}  Privileged instruction.

FAULTING_IP: 
+92760
ffffc582`04c408b3 0f22e0          mov     cr4,rax

CONTEXT:  ffffc581ffd36c70 -- (.cxr 0xffffc581ffd36c70)
rax=0000000000000274 rbx=ffffc582035ee340 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=ffffc582035ee340 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=ffffc58204c408b3 rsp=ffffc581ffd37678 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000024cc0  r9=ffffc582035ee000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=ffffd9099d23a020 r12=0000000000000206 r13=000000000022821c
r14=ffffd9099b61a140 r15=0000000000000030
iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000006
ffffc582`04c408b3 0f22e0          mov     cr4,rax
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CODE_CORRUPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  VBoxHeadless.e

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from ffffc58204c40732 to ffffc58204c408b3

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffc581`ffd37678 ffffc582`04c40732 : 00000000`00000010 fffff802`f8125166 
ffffc581`00000000 fffff802`f8192760 : 0xffffc582`04c408b3
ffffc581`ffd37680 00000000`00000010 : fffff802`f8125166 ffffc581`00000000 
fffff802`f8192760 00000000`000004df : 0xffffc582`04c40732
ffffc581`ffd37688 fffff802`f8125166 : ffffc581`00000000 fffff802`f8192760 
00000000`000004df 00000000`00000000 : 0x10
ffffc581`ffd37690 ffffc581`00000000 : fffff802`f8192760 00000000`000004df 
00000000`00000000 00000000`03fa4c10 : VMMR0+0x25166
ffffc581`ffd37698 fffff802`f8192760 : 00000000`000004df 00000000`00000000 
00000000`03fa4c10 00000000`00000000 : 0xffffc581`00000000
ffffc581`ffd376a0 00000000`000004df : 00000000`00000000 00000000`03fa4c10 
00000000`00000000 ffffc581`00000003 : VMMR0+0x92760
ffffc581`ffd376a8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`03fa4c10 00000000`00000000 
ffffc581`00000003 fffff802`f589c64c : 0x4df


MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffc581ffd36c70 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

Followup: memory_corruption
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable Hyper-V in Windows man ... Worked here